# How to calculate the quaternion that represents a triangle's 3D rotation?

Tags: quaternions

Or to look at it another way, let's say we have 2 same size triangles located and orientated at different parts of 3D space. How do you calculate the quaternion that describes the rotation such that applying the quaternion to triangle A would have it sit at triangle B? It is difficult to see how finding the normal of A and B and calculating the quaternion from this would work because the normal vector does not contain information about rotation (or rather, it assumes the standard base frame for the normals of both triangles thus throwing away valuable information). It seems you would need to find the vectors from each triangles (a, b, c) to the others (a, b, c) and somehow construct a quaternion out of this. Way beyond me, and could any mathematicians please dumb it down.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you are asking. Isn't rotating triangle A to sit at triangle B the same as rotating point A to sit at point B? Do you care about orientation / scale? Is it possible to do what you want with just a rotation?

Comment: A rotation isn't enough.  You may also need a translation.

Comment: Darcy Rayner: It is, but there are three points and their distance/rotation differs: for example, a triangle A facing south and a triangle B facing east, there has to be a quaternion that will rotate A to map B. Using normals to make the quaternion is problematic because the normals will be A(0,0,1) and B(1,0,0) regardless of whether the triagle B, for example, has been rotated 45 deg about the x axis while A remains unrotated. The quaternion has to be able to encompass the rotations about the 3 axis. How to do that is what I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First orient the normal vectors then the plane.

Source=(s1,s2,s3)

Target=(t1,t2,t3)

NormSource = (s1 - s2)cross(s1 - s3)

NormTarget = (t1 - t2)cross(t1 - t3)

Quat1 = getRotationTo (NormSource,NormTarget)

Quat2 = getRotationTo ( Quat1 * (s1 - s2),(t1 - t2) );

QuatFinal = Quat2 * Quat1

Comment: Thinking about it, the above will not work because the normal given by crossing the target will not retain the rotation out of which it was constructed. that is, the base frame (t and b axes) used to construct the norm may be rotated other than the base frame of the source, yet the norm calculated is simply a vector that cannot retain this rotation information. Therefore the quaternion constructed from nSource to nTarget will not have this crucial base frame rotation.

Comment: Yes, i.e. why I have seconds Quat2. It's the base frame rotation.

Comment: Sumeet I pulled the answer hopefully to get your attention. Could you please clarify the variables (st2 - st1); do you mean (s2 - s1) or (t2 - t1)?

Comment: I see. Quat1 is the rotation of norm from src to dest. Then rotate t vec by Quat1. Quat2 is rotation from rotated t to t at dest. QuatFinal is the agglomeration of these 2 rotations. Therefore (st2 - st1) must be (t2 - t1).

Comment: Yes, st1 is t1. Typo my mistake.

Comment: Also, you need (t2-t1) needs to be (t1-t2).  I'll make this edit too since this user hasn't been active since 2012.